# get selected text of the url

Tags: javascript, browser

I just wanted to know is it possible to get the selected text of the address bar.i.e if the clients selects the url text from the address bar it needs to be copied to the clipboard and shows a message. I couldn't find anything for the address bar access. I want to create this process on user's selection without any button click.The solution provided previously was for firefox..chrome doesn't provides anything to access url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text from Address Bar in Firefox extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759834/how-to-get-text-from-address-bar-in-firefox-extension)

Comment: its only for firefox..what if I want to access the url bar from chrome?

Comment: is there any way if the user selects copy on context menu or just presses ctrl+C then some msg or tooltip is to be shown that the msg is copied..

Comment: did you check that post ?..please read the answer of that post carefully

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with current JavaScript APIs.