# Load website and execute javascript based on input in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have an internal site with a search that contains a search field. What I want to do is based on a keyword and a value in chrome load that specific site, and input my value in the search field.

For instance:

typing in chrome address bar: "MyKeyWord TextToSearchFor" then chrome will load a specific url and execute javascript to input TextToSearchFor in the search field.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems to be impossible to get text from chrome address bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671555/get-text-not-url-from-address-bar-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) API.

<sup>See [GitHub omnibox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-omnibox/jbfhklldhgbomclinhlgbmjjiimafolo) and [other extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/omnibox?_category=extensions).</sup>